# Does the Test Studio Power App work with Desktop Applications?

Tags: automation, ui-automation, powerapps, software-quality

I am looking for a free Automation tool for a desktop application that works with Visual Basic and .net. I’ve tried many different ways but none seem to be too great. Most can’t pick up word inside a form that need to be clicked as an example. I saw the Test Studio Power App and didn’t know if that worked for anyone with Desktop Applications? Or anyone have suggestions?  Again looking for free tools, low code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not. Test Studio currently can only be used to test (automate) Power Apps (canvas) applications.